# Firefox 4: where is the history list on the back/forward buttons?

Tags: firefox

I like having the little drop down list on the Firefox Back/Forward button so that I can select a page in my history to go to instead of having to keep pressing the Back button.

The list disappeared in Firefox 4 Beta 7.  How do I get it back?

Comment: You can also hold the mouse button if you have a 1 button mouse but taking it away is CRAZY.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right-click on the forward/back buttons to bring up the list, this was also possible in Firefox 3

Comment: ...true, but not too different from *having to keep pressing the Back button*? Still, it is *faster* of course!

Comment: How so? It's the same number of clicks as the way I'm assuming the asker used to do it (by clicking the little arrow beside forward/back to bring up the list)

Comment: You're right, it *is* the same number of clicks too, I didn't realize that! And: the area where one needs to click is much larger than that little arrow. (But I can't upvote twice!)

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer keeping the drop-down menu as it was in FF3, there is now an add-on here - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/backforward-dropmarker/

Answer (score 1):

Click and hold on the back/forward button, and the menu will appear.  It's an alternate way to pull it up, if you don't like the idea of right-clicking.